# Null values are displayed as java.lang.Object@674621fd while performing select using the jobs.query API in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

While using **jobs.query API** to select the data from bigquery table, NULL values in the table are returned as object hashcode *java.lang.Object@674621fd*.

I want to retrieve those null values as it is. Can you please help me with this?

Below is the code that I am using:

```
QueryResponse query = bigquery.jobs().query(projectId, new QueryRequest().setQuery(querySql)).execute();

    for (TableRow row : query.getRows()) {
        for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
            System.out.print(field.getV());
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

ENvironment:
Java 1.8
Bigquery API V2 - google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev20200415-1.30.9.jar

Thanks,
Shruti

Comment: What are the contents of `POST` request, what is the version of API. Or to be specific, please create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can we reopen this case? I have attached the code snippet

Comment: Null values are displayed as `"null"` or cause `NullPointerExceptions`. It is impossible for them to display what you claim here.

Comment: @user207421 When I try to do **field.getV()** it returns me an object instead of null value in case of bigquery.

Comment: @shruti_gupta could you please try to change `System.out.print(field.getV())` to: `System.out.print(field.getV().toString())`, what will return a string representation of the object. Waiting for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this today. My requirement was to execute some logic if the value was `null`. I achieved this with [`com.google.api.client.util.Data#isNull`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/util/Data.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-).

Example:

```java
import com.google.api.client.util.Data;

// ...

private String getStringValue(TableCell cell) {
  return Data.isNull(cell.getV()) ? null : cell.getV().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the legacy BigQuery API works. For NULL values it returns the hashcode to avoid NPE.

To retrieve the actual null value, we need to use the Cloud Bigquery API https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery